# string.Replace(string, string) not giving me the expected results

Tags: c#, replace

In my opinion, I want to remove only '01|CF' out string '01|CFV,01|CFY,01|CF' to '01|CFV,01|CFY'. But have 3 mark '01|CF' in this string, so if replace string, i will take to result 'V,Y,'. I want to know how to solve that

```cs
string stringToSearch = "01|CF"; 
string stringToBeSearched = "01|CFV,01|CFY,01|CF";
```

Comment: on what basis??

Comment: I have edited your question and reworded it... Also I just tested your code, check [this .net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ORfkvG) and... It just works as you think it should. Very likely it was poor variable naming (I think you just checked the wrong variable because of the names you chose).

Comment: It returns `V,Y`, fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/32ad31

Comment: sorry, my English is poor, i've just edit my expect value "01|CFV,01|CFY', not 'V,Y,'

Comment: Why would you expect `01|CFV,01|CFY`? string.Replace does replace *ALL* the matches of the string to be searched. So if you tell it to remove `01|CF`  from `>>01|CF<<  V,  >>01|CF<<  Y,  >>01|CF<<` it will remove those three marked matches.

Comment: Not sure why you are expecting what you are expecting. It's going to replace every occurrence of `"01|CF"`. If you do that, all that's left is `"V,Y,"`

Comment: I wish comments markdown could be used to underscore text, it would sometimes be useful.

Comment: Take a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-7.0. Note that each overload includes _all occurences_

Comment: In my opinion, I want to remove only '01|CF' out string '01|CFV,01|CFY,01|CF' to '01|CFV,01|CFY'. But have 3 mark '01|CF' in this string, so if replace string, i will take to result  'V,Y,'. I want to know how to solve that.

Comment: @nguyenhuy289 Because the last match is also the end of the string you can do it kinda easily using substring and lastindexof. Check my answer

Answer (score 1):

First `01|CF` replace with `""` and remain `V,`

Second `01|CF` replace with `""` and remain `Y,`

And third `01|CF` replace with `""` and remain `nothing`

Result: `V,Y,`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In your comments you elaborate further into your problem and notice why it does display that output:

> I want to remove only `01|CF`' out string `01|CFV,01|CFY,01|CF` to `01|CFV,01|CFY`. But have 3 `01|CF` matches in this string, so if I use `string.Replace()`, I will take to result `V,Y,`. I want to know how to solve that.

The trick is using a different approach. You need to locate the last match of the `01|CF` using [string.LastIndexOf()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=net-7.0) and based on that index/position get the part of the string that you want using [string.Substring()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-7.0).

```cs
string stringToSearch = "01|CF"; 
string stringToBeSearched = "01|CFV,01|CFY,01|CF";
int lastMatchPosition = stringToBeSearched.LastIndexOf(stringToSearch);
string firstPart = stringToBeSearched.Substring(0, lastMatchPosition - 1);
string lastPart = string.Empty;
if (!stringToBeSearched.EndsWith(stringToSearch)) {

}
Console.WriteLine(firstPart);
```

It outputs:

> 01|CFV,01|CFY

Edit: In case there was more text after `01|CF` you can do another Substring the retrieve the remaining text:

```cs
string stringToBeSearched = "01|CFV,01|CFY,01|CFmoretext";
int lastMatchPosition = stringToBeSearched.LastIndexOf(stringToSearch);
string firstPart = stringToBeSearched.Substring(0, lastMatchPosition - 1);
string lastPart = string.Empty;
if (!stringToBeSearched.EndsWith(stringToSearch)) {
    lastPart = stringToBeSearched.Substring(lastMatchPosition + stringToSearch.Length);
}
Console.WriteLine(firstPart + lastPart);
```

Comment: in case string is' 01|CFV,01|CF,01|CFY', '01|CF' is not in last match. So how to remove only '01|CF' between ',' ?

Comment: @nguyenhuy289 Just think what the functions I used do and check the documentation. You can check it that is the case and do another substring if necessary.